# Rewrite a JSON array in PHP so that jQuery can read it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to create a JSON array in PHP that jQuery can use and access but for some reason It doesn't work. I get no error messages on  the client side nor in the server logs and if I access enc.php directly, it does work, but I'm not sure if the output is correct (the array format).


**What I want:**
I would like to access the data with jQuery using data[i][0] for the ID ([i] because it's in a loop), and data[i][1] for the message and so on.

*Maybe I'm trying to do this the wrong way, if so please help me by pointing me in the right direction or provide an example.*

My code:

The current **PHP code**:

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $fetchedid = $row['id'];
  $fetchedkey = $row['chat_key'];
  $fetchednonce = $row['chat_nonce'];
  $fetcheduser = $row['chat_user'];
  $fetchedmsg = $row['chat_msg'];

  $plainmsg = \Sodium\crypto_secretbox_open($fetchedmsg, $fetchednonce, $fetchedkey);
  $out = array('id' => $fetchedid, 'msg' => $plainmsg, 'user' => $fetcheduser);
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  ob_end_clean();
  echo json_encode($out);
}
```

**Result:**

```
{"id":297,"msg":"test message","user":"john"}
```

**My jQuery (Ajax) code:**

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "enc.php",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data) {
     console.log('Update success called');
     if (data == 2) {
       // No messages to fetch
     } else if (data == 3) {
       // Cookie Tampering detected
     } else if (data == 5) {
       $("#chat").remove();
       alert("Den här chatten är stängd (tiden har gått ut).");
       window.location.href = "/?logout=safe";
     }
     else {
     for (i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
       var mid = data[i][0];
       $.cookie("cmid", mid);
       var from = data[i][1];
       var msg = data[i][2];
       $("#chat").append('<div class="left spotmsg"><div class="chat-avatar pull-left"><img src="/img/them.png" alt="avatar" width="48" height="48"></div><div class="message"><div class="arrow-left"></div><p><strong>@'+from+'</strong></p><p class="txt">'+msg+'</p></div></div>');
     }
     $('textarea').focus();
     $(".chat_area").animate({ scrollTop: $(".chat_area")[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
 }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem stems from the fact that your result is not the json for an array of objects but a simple object, so the line

```
 for (i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
```

never iterates as data does not have a length. you want your result to look like

#### Result :

```
[
    {"id":297,"msg":"test message","user":"john"}
]
```

that way it will also hold more than one john ;)

#### suggestion

so I believe your php should be :

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$out = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //... your code doesn't change here

    $plainmsg = \Sodium\crypto_secretbox_open($fetchedmsg, $fetchednonce, $fetchedkey);
    //here we append to $out
    $out[] = array('id' => $fetchedid, 'msg' => $plainmsg, 'user' => $fetcheduser);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    ob_end_clean();
    //echo json_encode($out);// not yet...
}
echo json_encode($out);//but now!
```

Comment: Thank you! with the code you provided I got a reply from jQuery, how ever, it says that the data is undefined? Do i need to change my jQuery code aswel?

Comment: I wouldn' expect it, no. try to call `console.log(data)` to see what comes back (or go to the Network tab of your browser's dev tools) ?

Comment: Ignore that. This does indeed work for my situation, only thing to note is that I had to change data[i][0] to data[i].id  ! The reason why I choose your answer is because this suits my situation and it allows me to continue to use for (i = 0; i < data.length; ++i)

Comment: Ok thanks! I had missed these `data[i][0]` calls. Happy it works!

Answer (score 2):

You can access object using `.` notation. To access `values` use `key`. for example to access `id` use `data.id`. If you have object you can't loop using length.

```
           var mid = data.id; //specify key to access id
           $.cookie("cmid", mid);
           var from = data.user;
           var msg = data.msg;
           $("#chat").append('<div class="left spotmsg"><div class="chat-avatar pull-left"><img src="/img/them.png" alt="avatar" width="48" height="48"></div><div class="message"><div class="arrow-left"></div><p><strong>@'+from+'</strong></p><p class="txt">'+msg+'</p></div></div>');
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you are outputting individual JSON strings in your while loop which is not correct because the combined output is invalid JSON. The solution is to build an array and then output the array at the end.

```
$arr = array();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $fetchedid = $row['id'];
  $fetchedkey = $row['chat_key'];
  $fetchednonce = $row['chat_nonce'];
  $fetcheduser = $row['chat_user'];
  $fetchedmsg = $row['chat_msg'];

  $plainmsg = \Sodium\crypto_secretbox_open($fetchedmsg, $fetchednonce, $fetchedkey);
  $out = array('id' => $fetchedid, 'msg' => $plainmsg, 'user' => $fetcheduser);

  $arr[] = $out;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
ob_end_clean();
echo json_encode($arr); // encode the final array
```

Now, your output can contain multiple chat messages and is valid JSON, such as:

```
[{"id":297,"msg":"test message","user":"john"}, {"id":300,"msg2":"test2 message","user":"john"}]
```

In the JavaScript, refer to the property names instead of `[0]`, `[1]` etc:

```
var mid = data[i].id;
$.cookie("cmid", mid);
var from = data[i].user;
var msg = data[i].message;
```